# How much does the Spotify app use the network?

Tags: spotify

Spotify is a P2P application and so I assume it uses quite a bit of network traffic downloading and sharing tracks. Can a Spotify guru tell me if it does this only when the player is in use (eg when you are browsing or play tracks) or all the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being a P2P application, it will be using network traffic when:

- You are requesting data from peers
- Peers are requesting data from you

so even if you aren't listening yourself, you could be uploading to other users.

To quote [the Spotify wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotify):

> The contents of each client's cache is
>   summarized in an index which is sent
>   to the Spotify stream hub upon
>   connecting to the service. This index
>   is then used to inform other clients
>   about additional peers they can
>   connect to for fetching streamed data
>   for individual tracks being played.
>   **This is accommodated by each client,
>   upon startup, acting as a server
>   listening for incoming connections
>   from other Spotify users, as well as
>   intuitively connecting to other users
>   to exchange cached data as
>   appropriate. There are currently no
>   official details from the developers
>   about how many connections and how
>   much of a user's upstream bandwidth
>   the Spotify client will use when
>   streaming to other users**; the Spotify
>   client offers no way for the user to
>   configure this, but this may change in
>   the future.
>   Audio streams are in the Vorbis format
>   at q5 (approx ~160 kbit/s), or
>   optional q9 (approx ~320kbit/s)
>   for premium subscribers, the highest
>   streaming rate for any online service.

Comment: so as long as the tray icon is there it could be streaming to others?

Comment: you are correct

Comment: Spotify seems to have phased out its P2P method. Source: https://techcrunch.com/2014/04/17/spotify-removes-peer-to-peer-technology-from-its-desktop-client/

Answer (score 0):

The amount of network data that the Spotify app uses can vary based on several factors, including the audio quality settings, whether you're streaming or downloading music, and the duration of usage. Here are some general guidelines:

Streaming Quality:

Higher quality settings use more data. For example, streaming at "Very High" quality consumes more data compared to "Low" or "Normal" quality.
Downloading Music:

Downloading music for offline listening uses data to retrieve the songs. The amount of data depends on the file size of the songs.
Usage Time:

The longer you use the app, the more data it will use, especially if you're streaming music continuously.
Background Data:

If the app is allowed to run in the background, it may use data to refresh playlists and recommendations even when you're not actively using it.
To control your data usage on Spotify, you can:

Adjust streaming quality in the app settings.
Download music only when connected to Wi-Fi.
Monitor your data usage through your device settings.
For precise information on your data usage, you can check your device's data usage statistics or refer to Spotify's settings within the app. Keep in mind that these details may be subject to updates, and it's always a good idea to check the latest information from Spotify directly or through your device settings.

Comment: Is this ChatGPT?

Comment: Here is source: https://spotypremium.com/history-of-spotify/